# NASM. Расположение секций

Tags: nasm, линковка

**Задача**: Написать на NASMе программу следующего вида

```
section .data
db      0x55,0xAA
TIMES   0x18 db 0
db      "PCIR"

    section .text
global main
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

и получить бинарь с той же структурой.

**Проблема**: Секции text и data меняются местами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: как получить структуру, которую я описал в исходнике?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что порядок секций в выхлопе ассемблера фиксирован в зависимости от выдаваемого формата. Если действительно так, то надо менять порядок секций линкером, если я правильно понял бегло прочитанный ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_19.html

Comment: Вы все верно сказали. Я проморгал этот пункт. А в примере черным по белому описана подобная структура

Comment: Оказалось, что всё-таки можно (я проверял для -f bin). Решение в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
section .data
db      0x55,0xAA
TIMES   0x18 db 0
db      "PCIR"

    section .text follows=.data
global main
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

даёт

```
00000000 55 AA 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00  U...............
00000010 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 50 43 │ 49 52 00 00  ..........PCIR..
00000020 66 31 C0 C3 │                                          f1..
```